# Find next available computer name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find the next available computer name in out domain.  Our computers use a naming format 
departmentName001

departmentName003

departmentName004

...

departmentName999

I can find the existing computer accounts and add 1 but I can't work out for to get it to start looking at 001, I'm aware of the use of `"{0:d3}" -f` but I'm not using it correctly.  Can anyone help?

```
function GetComputerList($ComputerName)
{
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = “LDAP://dc=domain,dc=local”
$objSearcher.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=$ComputerName))")
$colProplist = "name"
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
    foreach ($i in $colPropList){[void]$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$objComputer = $objResult.Properties; $objComputer.name}
}


$HostName = Finance
$unit="{0:d3}" -f $_

$num = GetComputerList("$HostName*") | Foreach {[int]($_.Name)} | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Last 1 
$name = $HostName+($unit+($num+1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it gets all computer with name starting with 'departmentName', strips all a-z characters, leaving just the numbers, converts the numbers to integers and sorting them to find the largest one:

```
$searcher = [ADSISearcher]'(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=departmentName*))'
$searcher.PageSize = 1000
$last = $searcher.FindAll() | Foreach-Object { [int]($_.Properties.name -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Last 1
$digitLength = "$last".Length
$NewComputerName = "{0}{1:D$digitLength}" -f 'departmentName',($last+1)
$NewComputerName
```

EDIT:

```
# get next available number in a range of numbers. returns 5 for 1,2,3,4,6,7,9
$number = $searcher.FindAll() | Foreach-Object { [int]($_.Properties.name -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object    

for($i=0; $i -lt $number.length; $i++) {if( $number[$i+1]-$number[$i] -gt 1) {$number[$i]+1; break} }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however it doesn't quite perform the task.  Specifically, it moves to the largest value, where there maybe a smaller value that is available (e.g computer 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, it would use 10, and not 2).

More importantly it doesn't pad with leading zeros 000 that {0:d3} does.  Therefore if you use the 'Finance' and no 'Finance*' machine exists it starts with Finance1 and not Finance001 and if you use the name Sales where the last name for Sales is Sales047 it picks the name Sales48 (with no leading 0)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$searcher = [ADSISearcher]'(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=Finance*))'
$searcher.PageSize = 1000
$last = $searcher.FindAll() | Foreach-Object {
[string]($_.Properties.name -replace '\D')  }  | Sort-Object     
$i = 0
$last | % { if ($i -ne [int]$_ ) { $new = $i.tostring().padleft(3,'0'); break } 
else 
{ $i++ }}

$newComputerName = "finance" + $new
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the information in this post I have made a few changes and tweaks to the code for my environment to check more than just AD.. and also fixed it not filling in blanks at the start of a range.. I have blogged it here: [AutoGeneratingServer Names](http://blog.wallis2000.co.uk/2015/04/auto-generating-server-names.html)

copy of the code here too, and I know it can be refactored lots!

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

# ********************************************************
$startOfName = "xxxYYYZZWEB"
# ********************************************************

# VMWare Details
$ADVIServers = @("vsphere1.blah.local","vsphere2.blah.local","vsphere3.blah.local","vsphere4.blah.local")
$StandAloneHosts = @()

# DNS Details
$DNSServer = "xxxxxx.blah.local"

# SCCM 2012 Details
$SCCM2012SiteServer = "sccm2012.blah.local"
$SCCM2012SiteCode = 'SiteCode' 

# SCCM 2007 Details
$SCCM2007SiteServer = "sccm2007.blah.local"
$SCCM2007SiteCode = 'SiteCode2' 

# SCOM 2007 Details
$SCOMServer = "scom.blah.local"

# Create Empty Arrays
$VMNumbers = @()
$ADnumbers = @()
$DNSNumbers = @()
$SCCM2012Numbers = @()
$SCCM2007Numbers = @()
$SCOM2007Numbers = @()


# VMWare

    Write-Verbose "Processing VMware"
    Add-PSSnapin vmware.vimautomation.core -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Set options for certificates and connecting to multiple enviroments
    $null = Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$False
    $null = Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -DefaultVIServerMode Multiple -Scope User -Confirm:$False

    # Connect to each AD Authenticated viServer
    foreach ($VIServer in $ADVIServers){$null = Connect-VIServer $VIServer -verbose:$false} 

    # Connect to standalone host
    foreach ($Host in $StandAloneHosts){$null = Connect-VIServer $Host -User 'usernamehere' -Password 'passwordhere' -verbose:$false} 

    # get next available number in a range of numbers.
    $VMNames = Get-VM -Name "$($startOfName)*" -verbose:$false |select Name
    $VMNames |select Name | Foreach-Object {Write-Verbose $_.Name} | Sort-Object
    $VMNumbers = $VMNames |select Name | Foreach-Object {[int]($_.Name -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object
    Write-Verbose "$($VMNumbers.Count) Matching entries found"

# Active Directory

    Write-Verbose "Processing Active Directory"

    # Issue Query
    $searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=$($StartOfName)*))"
    $searcher.PageSize = 1000

    # get next available number in a range of numbers. returns 5 for 1,2,3,4,6,7,9 From AD
    $ADNames = $searcher.FindAll() | Foreach-Object {[string]$_.Properties.name} | Sort-Object
    $ADNames | Foreach-Object {Write-Verbose $_} | Sort-Object  
    $ADnumbers = $ADNames | Foreach-Object {[int]($_ -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object  
    Write-Verbose "$($ADnumbers.Count) Matching entries found"

# Search DNS

    Write-Verbose "Processing DNS"

    # Import DNS module
    Import-Module dnsShell -Verbose:$false
    $DNSNames = get-dnsRecord -server $DNSServer -RecordType A -Zone blah.local | select Name |where {$_.Name -like "$($startOfName)*"} 
    $DNSNames | Foreach-Object {Write-Verbose $_.Name} | Sort-Object -Unique
    $DNSNumbers = $DNSNames | Foreach-Object {[int]($_.Name -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object -Unique
    Write-Verbose "$($DNSNumbers.Count) Matching entries found"

# Search SCCM

    Write-Verbose "Processing SCCM 2012"

    # Query SCCM2012 Env
    $SCCM2012Members = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $SCCM2012SiteServer -Namespace  "ROOT\SMS\site_$SCCM2012SiteCode" -Query "SELECT * FROM SMS_FullCollectionMembership WHERE CollectionID='SMS00001' AND Name LIKE '$($startOfName)%' order by name" | select Name -Unique
    $SCCM2012Members |select Name | Foreach-Object {Write-Verbose $_.Name} | Sort-Object
    $SCCM2012Numbers = $SCCM2012Members |select Name | Foreach-Object {[int]($_.Name -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object
    Write-Verbose "$($SCCM2012Numbers.Count) Matching entries found"

    Write-Verbose "Processing SCCM 2007"

    # Query SCCM2007 Env
    $SCCM2007Names = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $SCCM2007SiteServer -Namespace "root\sms\site_$SCCM2007SiteCode" -class "SMS_R_System" -filter "Name LIKE `"$startOfName%`"" |select Name | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique
    $SCCM2007Names |select Name | Foreach-Object {Write-Verbose $_.Name} | Sort-Object
    $SCCM2007Numbers = $SCCM2007Names |select Name | Foreach-Object {[int]($_.Name -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object
    Write-Verbose "$($SCCM2007Numbers.Count) Matching entries found"

# Search Production SCOM 2007

    Write-Verbose "Processing SCOM 2007"

    #Initialize SCOM SnapIn
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Client -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -verbose:$false

    #Connect to Production SCOM 2007 Env.
    $null = New-ManagementGroupConnection -ConnectionString $SCOMServer

    #Connect to SCOM Provider
    Push-Location 'OperationsManagerMonitoring::'

    # Get Agents Matching Name
    $SCOM2007Names = Get-ManagementServer |Get-Agent |Where {$_.Name -like "$($startOfName)*"}
    $SCOM2007Names | Foreach-Object {Write-Verbose $_.Name} | Sort-Object
    $SCOM2007Numbers = $SCOM2007Names | Foreach-Object {[int]($_.Name -replace '\D').Trim() } | Sort-Object
    Write-Verbose "$($SCOM2007Numbers.Count) Matching entries found"

    # Return to previous location
    Pop-Location

# Merge arrays adding a zero so we allways start issuing numbers from the beginning (ie 001)
$list = @(0) + $VMNumbers + $ADnumbers + $DNSNumbers + $SCCM2012Numbers + $SCCM2007Numbers + $SCOM2007Numbers

# Remove Duplicates numbers from the array and sort into numerical order
$list = $list | Sort-Object -Unique

Write-Verbose "Used numbers after sorting: $($list)"

# Determine if next server name is a gap in the sequence in the array
for($i=0; $i -lt $list.length; $i++) {
    if( $list[$i+1]-$list[$i] -gt 1) {
        # The gap between the current server number and the next element in the array is greater than 1
        # So we have an available number we can use.
        # TODO: - Add support for consecutive numbers IE build 6 servers with consecutive numbers.
        $num = "{0:000}" -f ($list[$i]+1)
        break
    }
}

# If no gap found in the sequence then use the next number from the sequence in the array
if ($num -eq $null) {
    $num = "{0:000}" -f (($list[-1]+1))
}

# Construct new name
$NewComputerName = "{0}{1}" -f $startOfName,$num

# Create DNS Record to 'reserve / mark the name as in use'
Write-Verbose "Creating DNS Reservation"
New-DnsRecord -Name $NewComputerName -IPAddress "127.0.0.1" -Zone blah.local -Type A -Server $DNSServer

write-output $NewComputerName
```